# Change colors in Emacs ido mode

Tags: emacs

I've installed Emacs-starter-kit (https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit/), and I've customized the colour scheme.
But in the minibuffer (in ido mode, which is default in Emacs-starter-kit) red colour looks different.
[screenshot http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/5/5/upload/7133d11f.jpg](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/5/5/upload/7133d11f.jpg)
How I can customize colours in the ido minibuffer and make it looks in the same way as in regular buffers?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the faces for ido and how I set them in my .emacs:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(ido-subdir ((t (:foreground "#66ff00")))) ;; Face used by ido for highlighting subdirs in the alternatives.
 '(ido-first-match ((t (:foreground "#ccff66")))) ;; Face used by ido for highlighting first match.
 '(ido-only-match ((t (:foreground "#ffcc33")))) ;; Face used by ido for highlighting only match.
 '(ido-indicator ((t (:foreground "#ffffff")))) ;; Face used by ido for highlighting its indicators (don't actually use this)
 '(ido-incomplete-regexp ((t (:foreground "#ffffff")))) ;; Ido face for indicating incomplete regexps. (don't use this either)
```

I found them by doing <kbd>M-x</kbd> set-face-foreground <kbd>RET</kbd> and then typing "ido-" and using completion to get the available face names.

It may be simpler to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> customize-face and then using completion like above to customize the faces using the simple interface.

Comment: arghh, I couldnt understand why this didnt work for me.. finally figured it out, make sure you have faces enabled `(setq ido-use-faces 't)`. It was disabled by flx-ido in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize ido faces with
<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`customize-group`<kbd>RET</kbd>`ido`<kbd>RET</kbd>
and then search for `face`.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to find which faces are available (than `set-face-foreground`) is `list-faces-display`.

You can also let Emacs do its customization thing, and then move the code - from its rather clueless location at EOF of *.emacs* into the font hook:

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-font-lock-mode)
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
          '(lambda()
             (custom-set-faces
                 .
                 .
```

IMHO that's the best and clearest way to enable font-locking.

`global-font-lock-mode` will enable font locking in all buffers. Call this (autoloaded) function interactively to toggle font-locking.